# Silverlight Debugging in Visual Studio stops working when open a new window

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, debugging

I have an aspx page that hosts a silverlight application.

Debugging works fine and breakpoints in the silverlight app are hit when I go to the page directly but when I have the page launch in a new window from its hosting ASP.NET application the breakpoints stop getting hit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are using IE8 which launches multiple processes to host web pages.  What is happening is that the new window has its page hosted by a different iexplore process than the one Visual studio is currently attached to.

Simply open the "Attach to process..." dialog and attach to other iexplore processes that aren't current attached.

Alternatively if this is still a problem, for debug purposes you can disable this IE behaviour using a registry calue change.  In the key:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main

Modify the value of `TabProcGrowth` to 0.  Restore the default of "small" after you're done debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the process using visual studio in case you are running it separately and then check if your break points are hit.