# VS 2013 exception when try to debug silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-10, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS2013. 
But I can't debug my silverlight application in it.
When I press F5 I see the following error message:

[image: error message]

Error message text: The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit processed or 64-bit dumps. Please use the 64-bit version instead.

My operating system is Windows 7 x64.

Everything worked well on VS2012.

One more thing: I do can attach debugger manually to the process "iexplorer.exe".

**UPDATE:** The bug was not related to VS2013. It's related to IE10 (that was required to install VS2013). Silverlight doesn't support debugging in x64 mode. And IE10 vice-versa runs ONLY in x64. It can run separate tabs in x86 (using "Enhanced Protected Mode") but it runs new processe for each tab (the main iexplorer.exe stays in x64). I've downgraded to IE9 and everything works fine now. But if anybody knows how to make it work with IE10, I would appreciate it.

Comment: another option: just use Firefox or Chrome for debugging purposes

Comment: I would like to do it. But for the rest of browsers I get another exception: "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub."

Comment: Seems to be OK in IE11 as well.  I'm pretty sure Silverlight does support debugging in 64-bit mode.

Comment: You are lucky, john_cat. For me it doesn't work in IE11 as well :)

Comment: I had the same problem with VS2012 and IE10, I downgraded to IE9 and just works fine

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issues. In my case it is found that the issue is not with the visual studio but with the IE on windows 64 making debugging silver-light applications to fail.

The solutions found on web are to change settings in IE. Links provided below hope it helps

[Change tab proc growth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625866/silverlight-debugging-in-visual-studio-stops-working-when-open-a-new-window)
[link2](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774460/cannot-debug-silverlight-win7-x64-ie10)

Answer (score -1):

Are you hosting this app in a Web Application? If so, go to the Web project Properties and check "Silverlight Applications" section. In the "Add Silverlight Application" menu, check "Enable Silverlight debugging".

Have you tried debugging this app in OOB mode?